# Numerically integrate over an Interpolating function

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I would like to integrate over an interpolating function, which itself is the output of `NDSolve` in the following code. Unfortunately, I get an error code, saying that "The integrand ... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0, 0.735185}}.".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
h[s_] := 
  (RC[s] + ph)^-σ/((αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)) + (RC[s] + ph)^(-(ρ/σ))) 
    (w - Tw + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s - FC - TC);
V[s_] := 
   αh ((RC[s] + ph)^(-(ρ/σ))  + (αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)))^((1 - ρ)/ρ) 
     (w - Tw + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s - FC - TC) - P;
sol = Solve[{D[V[s], s] == 0}, RC'[s]];
solprime = Equal @@@ Flatten[sol];

αh = 0.2; αz = 0.2; γ = 5; ph = 0.01; pf = 1; FC = 0.1; 
tC = 0; TC = 0; w = 1; ρ = 0.2; σ = 1/(1 - ρ); L = 1; RA = 0.1;
R0 = 1; S = 1; P = 1; n = 7; G = 1; Tw = 1;

popCitySize = RandomInteger[10, {n, 2}]; 
citySize = Table[1/4 i, {i, 1, n}];
Do[popCitySize[[i, 2]] = citySize[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
  {solND = 
     NDSolve[
       {solprime[[1]], RC[popCitySize[[i, 2]]] == RA}, 
       RC, 
       {s, 0, popCitySize[[i, 2]]}];
     pop = 
       NIntegrate[1/h[s] /. First[solND], {s, 0, popCitySize[[i, 2]]}]; 
     popCitySize[[i, 1]] = pop;}];
f = Interpolation[popCitySize];
R0 = NIntegrate[First[solND] - RA /. Integrate -> NIntegrate, {s, 0, f[1]}];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should give solND an argument:

```
R0 = NIntegrate[(RC /. solND[[1]])[s] - RA , {s, 0, f[1]}] 
(*636.881*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that was the trick.

Comment: You're welcome!